# Image matching using edge detection

Tags: java, image, edge-detection

I am doing my final year Mca and my topic is image matching using edge detection.

I have an Image at hand where the subject is not smiling, and two other images.

1. Bigger image containing the image at hand as a part of the image
2. Same as the image at hand with (some modification like smiling)

Now I want to check for presence in the first case, matching in the second case.

My approach:

I will find edges for all the given images-to reduce the amount of data to check.

I'm stuck on how to proceed. Any suggestions are extremely appreciated.

Comment: I can't understand your post. Can you maybe make it more precise? Also: what will you do with edges? Will you try to find some correspondence points? Do you have an idea how will you do that? How many images do you have in your training/classification sets?

Comment: I have edited this question for clarity to the absolute best of my ability. Please feel free to refine my edits as needed. @Margus, could you take a look at this and possibly improve it more?

Answer (score 3):

I have been Java user for years and I can do virtually anything, but ... as I found Mathematica about 2 years ago, I really started to love Mathematica. This is kind of problem I would use Mathematica to solve.

Just take a look at [image processing reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ImageProcessing.html).

Example of `ImageCorrelate` function:
[image]

Comment: Is this really helpful for him? He has to implement his own matching using edge detection.

Comment: Well that depends on what kind of engineer he is. Mathematica greatly simplifies mathematical computation and image preprocessing using rapid prototyping is just fun (in Java it can be fun, but it is most likely more time consuming process). Mathematica also contains J/Link to interconnect with Java or Java server side - if for whatever reason he does prefer using his prototype.

Answer (score 0):

[CVOnline](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/) is a great source of computer vision algorithms.   The section on [edge detection](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/cgi/rbf/CVONLINE/entries.pl?TAG1285) can probably point you in the right direction.