# Reading palm line pixels from an image of human palm

Tags: java, image-processing

I am working on a software which takes an image of human palm as input and then reads the lines of this palm to give prediction. We are successfully able to read the pixels of this image. But, still we are nowhere near reading exactly the pixels of line.

If anybody has worked on such a project, please help.

I have tried Googling for this, but the results are not satisfactory. I'd like to get some inputs as in, what should be the proper methodology to perform reading of an image? Is there any API available for this in Java?

Images:

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 4]
[image: Image 5]
[image: Image 6]
[image: Image 7]
[image: Image 8]
[image: Image 9]

Comment: Somewhat beyond the scope of SO. Possibly better suited for [CSTheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)??

Comment: This is completely off-topic for CSTheory. As it stands, it is a bad question no matter where you put it. For instance, what are the conditions during image acquisition ? Can you include sample images ? Currently, you can only get generic bad answers.

Comment: @mmgp: I'd add the images after posting this comment. The conditions are quite simple. We'd be reading the palm using a normal scanner and then would like to scan this image to read the correct pixels of palm lines. I'm still not able to get a correct path for performing this action. I would be grateful if you have any links to share with me for this purpose.

Comment: @Dukeling: I don't have much knowledge about CSTheory. Can u pls help a bit more with few examples.

Comment: @mmgp: I tried posting images. But can't. Need 10 reputations for that. Can i mail that to you? could you provide me your mail-id.

Comment: @MayankSehgal You could add links to images stored on imgur.com or anywhere else (and higher reputation users could optionally convert these to in-line images).

Comment: @Dukeling Following are the links for images I'm parsing:

http://imgur.com/EyR1Bqr
http://imgur.com/kfi9t0o
http://imgur.com/2q6KEHw
http://imgur.com/Axy86u7
http://imgur.com/gWplmVV
http://imgur.com/JN1BWTw
http://imgur.com/UF9r4EM
http://imgur.com/KyYj7Py
http://imgur.com/GzokVHF

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5104073/684934 might be relevant

Comment: how is the progression of your development of the software?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible options to help you get started on this:

1. Java2D
2. JAI - Java Advanced Imaging

Comment: I'm reading about Java2D. Can you site some examples in this context where where Java2D is used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your responses. Your responses have helped me to great extent. 
Meanwhile, I've been reading Image Thresholding. The process I'm following is somewhat like this:

1) I'm sure that images my software would be getting as input would be of the above type only. That is, the images would be gray-scale and would be of hands and nothing else. 
2) I'm choosing a threshold value against which I'll check pixels of this hand image.
3) If the value of this pixel is less than my threshold, I'll convert that pixel into black.
4) Otherwise I'd be converting it into white.

This way I'd have an image that contains only black and white pixels. I suppose after this I can proceed with finding the palm lines. Please suggest me if anybody has any steps to proceed further.